# How do I resolve inter-library include dependencies?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have written a C++ library (let's call it **PhysicsLib**) that uses the Bullet library for some physics computations. I have created a class `PhysicsClass`, which includes two header files from Bullet in its own header file **PhysicsClass.h** in order to access a few Bullet classes.

When using this PhysicsLib library, one has to include the classes used — like always — but this causes problems when the `PhysicsClass` is used. When I create the application **PhysicsApplication** and include PhysicsClass.h the compiler notices that this header file in turn depends on the header files from Bullet. Now, when I want to compile my application PhysicsApplication, I have to not only specify the include directory of PhysicsLib, but also the include directory of Bullet.

What solutions are available? **Do I just forward declare every class from Bullet that's used by `PhysicsClass`?** I've never needed to forward declare classes from 3rd party libraries, which makes me question the design of my library PhysicsLib.

Comment: Can you post the `PhysicsClass.h` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options: either you make Bullet a part of your library's *interface,* or restrict its use to your library's *implementation.*

### Interface

The first is pretty much what you're doing now: make use of Bullet types, functions, etc. in the interface part of your library, and thus "admit" that in order to develop against your library, client code must set up Bullet for use in development too.

You should be upfront about this in your documentation, and, depending on what build mechanisms you offer to your clients, make setting up Bullet as much a part of them as possible. As an example of that: if you were using CMake and shipping a package config file for you library, that package config file should locate Bullet and set it up in your library's interface properties, or error out of Bullet cannot be found.

If you have an installer (or installer-like thing) for your library, you might consider providing one version with just your library and another one with Bullet packed in, too.

### Implementation

The other option is to restrict your use of Bullet to the implementation only. This effectively means "hiding" the fact that you're using Bullet at all. No interface header (= header for client consumption) of your library may refer to anything from Bullet. Use Pimpl and similar idioms to keep Bullet implementation-only. If necessary, wrap Bullet types in your own opaque wrappers so that the Bullet backend remains in your library's implementation only.